# Draw colors in Div based on two points

Tags: html, css, angular

Lets say, I have two points 0 to 300 with background color Red.

Now, I want to draw 0 to 75 Green, 75 to 150 Yellow. I have these from and two points and can give values from Typescript view model class.

```
<div style="background-color: red">
   <div style="background-color: green">
   </div>
   <div style="background-color: yellow">
   </div>
</div>
```

My scenario is much complex and having 6-7 different colors. Is my approach right or is there any better approach? My app is TypeScript and Angular 2.

Comment: what is two points here. is it some variable?

Comment: @Jonnysai Yes those are variables in typescript file.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngStyle or [style.background-color]

```
    <div [ngStyle]="randomcss()">  
        <div [ngStyle]="randomcss()">
   </div>
</div>
```

component

```
export class AppComponent {
    randomcss(){
      // based on your points return color 
     return {'background-color':'red'}
    }
}
```

Comment: your both div's contain same method. how is it going to work?

Comment: check my comment inside function. based on your input variables.  if(var1 >0 && var2 <76) return {'background-color':'red'} else if(var1 >76 && var2 <150) return {'background-color':'green'}

Comment: I think I haven't put my question in a right way. My two points(0 to 300) values vary. So based on these two points, we need to calculate the percentage of the other two points.